# FullCalendar intermittent loading error on Salesforce 1

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the Full Calendar and have a visualforce page that is enabled for Classic and Salesforce 1, it works perfectly on Classic, but occassionally our engineers are reporting they get at error when trying to load the page, or when clicking on one of the record links within the page.

The errors are:
net:err_blocked_by-_Resource
and
error parsing json response 'Unexpected token <' logged in? undefined

As it's an intermitent issue, I cannot seem to debug it at all. I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight into the errors?
My code is below.

```
<apex:page controller="UserCalendarController" readOnly="true" >
<link href="{!$Resource.fullBasicCalendarMinCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullBasicCalendarPrintMinCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.MomentMin}"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.fullBasicCalendarMinJS}"></script>
<script>
var WOTag = '{!WOTag}';
var PHTag = '{!PHTag}';
var PSTag = '{!PSTag}';
var TOINFINITY = moment().add(10, "days");
var TODAY = moment().add(1, "days");
var NOW = moment();
window.$userId = "{!$User.Id}";

function htmlEncode(value)
{
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

function newLineToBR(value)
{
    return value.replace(/(\n)+/g, '<br />'); 
}

$(document).ready(function() 
                  {
                      //Call the fullCallendar method. 
                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                          {
                              schedulerLicenseKey: '0760513013-fcs-1521451920',
                              editable: false,
                              aspectRatio: 0.75,
                              eventOrder: 'displayOrder',
                              eventRender: function (event, element, view) 
                              {
                                  var title = element.find('.fc-title, .fc-list-item-title');   
                                  var titleNode = title[0].childNodes[0];
                                  var encoded = htmlEncode(titleNode.innerHTML);
                                  titleNode.innerHTML = encoded;
                                 //title.html(title.text());
                              },
                              eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) 
                              {
                                  var tooltip = '';
                                  if (calEvent.tag == WOTag)
                                  {
                                      tooltip = '<div class=" tooltipevent WO-tooltipevent">'
                                      + calEvent.toolTipTitle +'<h3><br/>' + calEvent.toolTipContent + '<br/>'
                                      + '</div>';
                                  }
                                  else if (calEvent.tag == PHTag)
                                  {
                                      tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent PH-tooltipevent">'
                                      + '<h3>' + calEvent.toolTipTitle +'<h3><br/>' + calEvent.toolTipContent + '<br/>'
                                      + '</div>';
                                  }
                                      else if (calEvent.tag == PSTag)
                                      {
                                          tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent PS-tooltipevent">'
                                          + calEvent.toolTipTitle +'<h3><br/>' + calEvent.toolTipContent + '<br/>'
                                          + '</div>';
                                      }

                                  $("body").append(tooltip);
                                  $(this).mousemove(function(e) 
                                                    {
                                                        $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 1);
                                                        $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 2);
                                                    });
                              },                                 
                              eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) 
                              {
                                  $(this).css('z-index', 8);
                                  $('.tooltipevent').remove();
                              }, 
                              eventClick: function(calEvent)
                              {
                                 /* alert('Event url: ' + calEvent.url);
                                  if (calEvent.url)
                                  {
                                      window.open(calEvent.url, '_parent');
                                      return false;
                                  }*/
                              },
                              header: 
                              {
                                  left: 'prev,next today',
                                  center: 'title',
                                  right: 'listToday, listNext10Days, month'
                              },
                              defaultView: 'listToday',
                              views: 
                              {             
                                  month: 
                                  {
                                      weekends: false,
                                      fixedWeekCount: false,
                                      buttonText: 'Month'
                                  },
                                  listNext10Days:
                                  {
                                      type: 'list',
                                      duration: {days:TOINFINITY.diff(NOW, 'days')},
                                      buttonText: 'Next 10 days',
                                      weekends: false,
                                      displayEventTime: false
                                  },
                                  listToday:
                                  {
                                      type: 'list',
                                      duration: {days:TODAY.diff(NOW, 'days')},
                                      buttonText: 'Today',
                                      weekends: false,
                                      displayEventTime: false
                                  }
                              },
                              events: function(start, end, timezone, callback)
                              {
                                  console.log('Getting events for ' + start.toDate() + ' - ' + end.toDate());
                                  $('.loader').toggle();
                                  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                      '{!$RemoteAction.UserCalendarController.CalendarEvents}',
                                      start.toDate().toUTCString(),
                                      end.toDate().toUTCString(),
                                      function(result, event)
                                      {
                                          if (event.status)
                                          {
                                              for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                                              {
                                                  var r= result[i];
                                                  r.start = new Date(r.starts);
                                                  r.end = new Date(r.ends);
                                                  //r.toolTipContent = r.toolTipContent.replace(/(\n)+/g, '<br />');
                                                  //r.title = r.title.replace(/(\n)+/g, '<br />'); 
                                                  r.title = newLineToBR(htmlEncode(r.title));
                                                  r.toolTipContent = newLineToBR(htmlEncode(r.toolTipContent));
                                              }
                                              console.log(result);
                                              callback(result);
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              alert('ERROR:\n' + event.message + '\n' + event.where);
                                          }
                                          $('.loader').toggle();
                                      });                                     
                              }                                 
                          });                        
                  });
</script>

<style>
    .loader{display:none; position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; border-top: 16px solid #3498db; border-radius: 50%; width: 120px; height: 120px; animation: spin 2s linear infinite;}
    @keyframes spin {0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

     <!--Scheduled event classes-->
    .workOrder-scheduled{background:red ;border-color:red; color: white !important;}
    <!--.workOrder-scheduled td{background:red ;border-color:red; color: white !important;}-->
    .psWork-scheduled-liveDay{background:green ;border-color:green;}
    .psWork-scheduled-liveDay .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .psWork-scheduled-installDay{background:yellow ;border-color:yellow;}
    .psWork-scheduled-regDay{background:violet ;border-color:violet;}
    .psWork-scheduled-remoteInstall{background:teal ;border-color:teal;}
    .psWork-scheduled-remoteInstall .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .psWork-scheduled-iDStoreFlip{background:sienna ;border-color:sienna;}
    .psWork-scheduled-training{background:SpringGreen ;border-color:SpringGreen;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-holidayHalf{background:skyBlue; border-color:SkyBlue; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-holidayFull{background:blue; border-color:blue;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-holidayFull .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-bankHoliday{background:DarkBlue; border-color:DarkBlue; }
    .placeholder-scheduled-bankHoliday .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-sickness{background:green; border-color:green; color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-sickness .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-fs{background:red; border-color:red;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-fs .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-ps{background:orchid; border-color:orchid; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-support{background:darkViolet; border-color:darkViolet;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-support .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-training{background:orangeRed; border-color:orangeRed; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-unavailableAM{background:khaki; border-color:khaki; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-unavailablePM{background:khaki; border-color:khaki; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-office{background:DarkSeaGreen; border-color:DarkSeaGreen; color: black !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-garage{background:DarkSlateGray; border-color:DarkSlateGray;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-garage .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-shadowFS{background:DarkRed; border-color:DarkRed;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-shadowFS .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-shadowPS{background:PaleVioletRed; border-color:PaleVioletRed;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-shadowPS .fc-list-item-title{color: white !important;}
    .placeholder-scheduled-reminder{background:Gray border-color:Gray; color: white !important;}

    <!--Tooltip classes-->
    .tooltipevent {border-radius: 25px; padding: 20px; background:#98AFC7; position:absolute;z-index:10001;}
    .WO-tooltipevent {min-width:150px; min-height:100px; width:auto;  height:auto;}
    .PH-tooltipevent {min-width:150px; min-height:20px; max-width:150px;  height:auto; }
    .PS-tooltipevent {min-width:150px; min-height:50px; width:auto;  height:auto; }
</style>
<div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div> 
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Many thanks for any assistance

Comment: "one of the record links"...so you mean clicking on an event and triggering this code: `eventClick: function(calEvent)
                              {
                                 /* alert('Event url: ' + calEvent.url);
                                  if (calEvent.url)
                                  {
                                      window.open(calEvent.url, '_parent');
                                      return false;
                                  }*/
                              },`?

Comment: Or you mean clicking on a different date to move backwards or forwards in time (and thus triggering the `events:` function to run again?

Comment: It's not clear which bit of functionality you're actually referring to. It _sounds_ like it might be the second one, because the error sounds like maybe the remote server (which is supposed to send you events as JSON) is failing for some reason, and instead of returning an error message in JSON format it returns it in HTML format, and thus when JavaScript tries to parse the response as JSON it fails, because HTML is not JSON (the clue's in the "unexpected token <` - a HTML document would start with a `<` which isn't valid to start a JSON document).

Comment: So I would open your browser's network tools and keep causing it to reload the events (by moving between time periods) until you get a problem...and then see what response you actually got from the server. Once you know what that error is, you can potentially investigate the problem server-side. None of this sounds like an issue with fullCalendar itself.

Comment: I didn't think it would be an error with the calendar as it's working perfectly on the desktop, it's purely on the mobiles where we are having the issue. Thank you for you suggestion I will do as you suggested. Could that also be the issue for the 'net::err_blocked_by_resource' error?

Comment: net::err_blocked_by_resource - google doesn't return any results for that error...are you sure that's the correct error message? Which browser is generating that exactly, and what version, and on what mobile O/Ses are you seeing this?